# how to replace this in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have code with "this" ,How can I write same code without "this" ?

```js
var memory_array = ["red", "red", "green", "green", "blue", "blue", "brown", "brown", "yellow", "yellow", "gray", "gray", "white", "white","black","black"];
var memory_values = [];
var memory_tile_ids = [];
var tiles_flipped = 0;
Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function(){
    var i = this.length, j, temp;
    while(--i > 0){
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
        temp = this[j];
        this[j] = this[i];
        this[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You extended the functionality of the "Array" type,  so "this" is the given array. why would you like to remove "this", or, why did u choose to extend the prototype functionality?

Comment: It's a trick question. If you rewrite it without `this` it will not be the same code any more! You will get more useful responses if you explain what problem you are trying to solve and what you tried doing to solve it.

Comment: It is not possible to write a method - and that's what `memory_title_shuffle` is - without use of the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to pass in the array as an argument to a function and then just use the array to work on it.

```js
function memory_tile_shuffle(array){
    // You can also use a third argument array in forEach if you prefer
    array.forEach(function(item, i) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
        temp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    });
}
```